# Ajax response stops works after the first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**This is my situation**
I am using the below code for adding a designed div in my webpage, the div is added only the first time but after it stop working.

```
 $('#addanother').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.get(
                        "add_another_form_process.php", {
                        username: $("#username").val()
                        },
                        function (data) {
                            $("div#wall").html(data);

                        }
                    );
                });
```

Comment: Is `#addanother` getting changed by any way ?

Comment: **are there any console errors when you click?** is #addanother inside div#wall? div in div#wall is probably redundant - but that's not an issue

Comment: stop working? which line stop working

Comment: by stop i mean this code give response only a single time while i need it equal to the mouse clicks.

Comment: show the html near #addanother and #wall and #username

Comment: @BilalSaqib debug your code.

Comment: @FastSnail there are no console errors.

Comment: use .`prepend(data)` or `.append(data)` instead of `.html(data)` and try

Comment: You want to add content to div#wall each time you click?

Comment: @FastSnail does it require any changes in code for multiple times?

Comment: your code REPLACES html, doesn't add to it ... but that doesn't mean it's "stopped working", it just means there's no change ... what you need to do is put a `console.log(data)` just above the .html(data) line to see if the code is being called on every click

Comment: @ihemant360 Bingo! append works for me, Thanks dear

Comment: *dear*? how well do you know each other :p

Comment: **Thanks to All** for helping me.

Comment: Keep checking the xhr calls in console. you will find if ajax call is being executed or not. and response as well.

Answer (score 1):

use `.prepend(data)` or `.append(data)` instead of `.html(data)` and try

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that when you do .html(data) you are overwriting all the html content from the div, so you are not adding anything to the previous click call. Use .append(data) or .prepend(data) instead.

Comment: And `.html` will also unset all the listeners attached to earlier DOM element..(_Within the element on which `.html` is invoked_)